# How do I use the ctype.h library in a conditional statement?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, ctype

I am trying to write a function that capitalizes all words in a string using the ctype.h library. I used the isalpha(), isspace() and ispunct() functions in a conditional statement to check if the first letter of a word is an alphabet and if the character before it was whitespace or punctuation. If those conditions are met then the program converts the letter to uppercase using the toupper() function.

I ran the program and it doesn't seem to be working, it actually returned the same string input. I need someone to help me out so that I can learn and improve my C programming skills. I am learning C Programming online and I'm loving it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/**
 * *cap_string - Capitalize the first words of a string
 * @s: Argument pointer to char
 * Return: Pointer to s variable
 */

char *cap_string(char *s)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
                if (isalpha(s[i]) && (i == 0 || (isspace(s[i - 1]) || ispunct(s[i - 1]))))
                {
                        *s = toupper(s[i]);
                }
        }
        return (s);
}

/**
 * main - Check the code
 * Return: Always 0
 */

int main(void)
{
        char str[] = "Expect the best. Prepare for the worst. Capitalize on what comes.\nhello world! hello-world 012345
6hello world\thello world.hello world\n";
        char *ptr;

        ptr = cap_string(str);
        printf("%s", ptr);
        printf("%s", str);
        return (0);
}
```

Comment: `*s + i` ===> What do you think this does?

Comment: `*s + i` -> `*(s + i)` or even better: `s[i]`

Comment: OT: Why not use `!isalpha()` to determine if the previous character is NOT alphabetic...?

Comment: Ok, I just did and I got the same result. The truth is I have tried various iterations before coming here for help. If anyone could help me run the code and see if they can fix the problem. I'll greatly appreciate it.

`if (isalpha(s[i]) && !isalpha(s[i - 1]))`

Comment: @Haris I thought it's same as `*(s + I)` but thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already understood, `*s + i` is different from `*(s + i)` and you should write `s[i]` rather than `*(s + i)` for readability reasons (and readability is very important).

So a first correction would be this:

```
char* cap_string(char* s)
{
  int i;
  char* ps = s;

  for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(s[i]) && (isspace(s[i - 1]) || ispunct(s[i - 1])))
    {
      s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
  }
  return (ps);
}

int main()
{
  char test[] = "hello world, abc";
  cap_string(test);
  printf("%s", cap_string(test));
}
```

But there is still a problem in this code. If the sentence starts with a letter  (IOW `isalpha` returns `true`), you try to access the letter *before* the first letter which is at the index -1 and accessing an array out of bounds yields is undefined behaviour.

Therefore the condition should be

```
isalpha(s[i]) && (i == 0 || (isspace(s[i - 1]) || ispunct(s[i - 1])))
```

so you never access `s[-1]`.

IOW: if the first character is a letter, we don't need (and we don't want) to check if the preceeding character is a space of a punctuation character.

BTW: `char* ps = s;` is useless, you can just `return s;` because you don't change `s`.

Comment: I tried your conditional statement but I still got the same output. I have edited the code to include the main function in case you'll want to run and test it. I really do appreciate your time sir and I look forward to hearing from you again.

Thank you.

Comment: @MarkBruye Look very closely at the line with `toupper`, once in the code in my answer and once in your code.

Comment: @Mark It works perfectly fine. Did you save the code? I believe you're missing the `i == 0` part.

Comment: @Haris I did save and compile, same problem. I wish I could send a screenshot.

Comment: @MarkBruye don 't send a screen shot, copy / paste the output and as properly formatted text into your question. Did you try the verbatim code in this answer? It definitely works correctly. Is the code you compile and run exactly the code from this answer?

Comment: @MarkBruye check this: https://ideone.com/MxOuXo

Comment: @JabberwockyWow it worked. Now I understand why it didn't work. I was thinking `*s = toupper(s[i]);` points to the entire string meanwhile it only points to the index and I needed to use `s[i]` to take the new value, one character at a time.

I'm learning and I promise to work harder. Thank you guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: @MarkBruye I told you to look very closely at a specific line in your and in my code.

Answer (score 1):

1. `*s + i` is not `s[i]`, it's `s[0] + i`.
2. Even if you correct all occurrence of `*s + i` and `*s + i - 1` with `s[i]` and `s[i - 1]`. If i is `0`, the `s[i - 1]` will turn into `s[-1]`, which is undefined.